# Using delegate's methods when delegate is a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, delegation

I'm not sure if this is an Xcode 6 Swift-specific problem, but here it goes.

I have two classes, MyViewController and UtilViewController. UtilViewController has a delegate property of type UIViewController, because UtilViewController is designed to be used by all of my app's viewcontrollers. It also has a function createOrder() that will only ever be called by MyViewController. Because this function will only ever be called by MyViewController, inside of createOrder() there is a line that calls a function declared by MyViewController, like this

```
self.delegate!.methodInMyViewController()
```

However this throws an error in UtilViewController

```
'UIViewController' does not have a member named 'methodInMyViewController'
```

How can I preserve the modularity of having a UIViewController delegate, but also be able to call methods from my own viewcontrollers, which are a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: This is a good question. In Objective-C, you can specify class *and* protocol for a property: `@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController<UtilViewControllerDelegate>* delegate;`

Comment: Why don't you call `createOrder()` with a callback (closure) into MyViewController,  instead of using the generic delegate?

Comment: @MartinR how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your delegate as a MyViewController to tell the compiler that it is actually a MyViewController and can call that method.

```
(self.delegate! as MyViewController).methodInMyViewController()
```

Since delegate may not always be a MyViewController, you may want to check if it is before casting:

```
if self.delegate! is MyViewController{
    (self.delegate! as MyViewController).methodInMyViewController()
}
```

Comment: Does casting always preserve the original UIViewController? I assumed casting it would make a new object, which would be very bad for the event loop.

Comment: Or with optional casting: `if let mvc = self.delegate! as? MyViewController { mvc. methodInMyViewController () } `

Comment: It doesn't change anything about the actual object. It's just a way of telling the compiler that it can treat the object as a MyViewController

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (ab)using the generic delegate of `UtilViewController`, the `createOrder()`
method could take a *closure* (callback) parameter. For example:

```
func createOrder(callWhenDone:()->()) {
    // do stuff ...
    callWhenDone()
}
```

From within `MyViewController`, you would call the method as

```
utilVC.createOrder {
    // called from createOrder()
    self.methodInMyViewController()
}
```